# Adding and removing callbacks in Scala

Tags: scala

This more a "style" question... but it may be interesting.

I've written the following trait:

```
trait EventProducer[B] {

  private var listeners: List[B => Unit] = List()

  def addListener(newListener: B => Unit) {
    listeners = listeners :+ newListener
  }

  protected def fireEvent(event: B) {
    listeners.map(listener => {
      listener(event)
    })
  }
}
```

so far so good. Now I want to add a removeListener function... but hey, how do I do that? In Java that'd be easy, because instead of using an anonymous function I'd use a class and then I could just find it in the list by value and remove it. But here I've no reference to the function (unless I keep it and it is not practical). So what's a good way to implement this?

Comment: You can't. Keep the reference or you are lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at my micro library [Model](https://github.com/Sciss/Model/blob/master/src/main/scala/de/sciss/model/impl/ModelImpl.scala#L64). As @sschaef points out, you need to keep a reference to the function. So I am returning that from `addListener` (simplified):

```
class Model[U] {
  type Listener = PartialFunction[U, Unit]

  private var listeners = Vector.empty[Listener]

  def addListener(pf: Listener): pf.type = {
    listeners :+= pf
    pf
  }

  def removeListener(pf: Listener): Unit = {
    val idx = listeners.indexOf(pf)
    if (idx >=0) {
      listeners = listeners.patch(idx, Nil, 1)
    }
  }

  // ...
  def isEmpty = listeners.isEmpty
}

val m = new Model[String]
val l = m.addListener {
  case "handshake" => println("launch rockets")
}
m.removeListener(l)
```

---

One thing to be very careful of is eta expansion, the use of methods in place of functions.

```
def foo(s: String) = println(s"Observed $s")

m.addListener(foo)
m.removeListener(foo)
assert(m.isEmpty)  // fails!
```

This last bit actually doesn't compile, because eta expansion only works for functions but not partial functions. In your code you use a function `B => Unit`, so be aware of this pitfall.

Comment: You could avoid the pitfall by returning opaque identifiers to the added listeners and require the use of those for the removal.

Comment: Interesting, even because I didn't know eta expansion. But I think in my use case it would be much easier to use a trait that has a callback method. That way any object that implements it, will have no need to keep the reference and just pass a reference to itself. This, unless ETA expansion has means to keep a reference to the object where the function belongs... does it?

Comment: @gotch4 I would stick to partial functions. As I said, they are not automatically generated from methods, so you don't have that trap. Note how Java 8 (or 7?) goes away from having explicit single-abstract-method interfaces to more concise lambda syntax. Use (partial) functions in Scala, that's what they are for.